# Mitmproxy multiple cookie headers

Tags: cookies, mitmproxy

I'm attempting to modify a saved flow's cookie and resend it, but the captured flow has multiple "cookie" headers.

```
cookie: uuid=3AF89B5E-1162-4236-B60D-6E4B05177A14
cookie: fp_token_7c6a6574-f011-4c9a-abdd5l05EcWM3T5o/whEw=
cookie: _gsid=84c8326882b6a81bad5
```

The goal is to update just one of the three values.  Attempts to set the cookie via `flow.request.headers["cookie"]="NEWVALUEHERE;fp_token_7c6a6574-f011-4c9a-abdd5l05EcWM3T5o/whEw=;_gsid=84c8326882b6a81bad5;"` results in the flow collapsing the three different cookie headers into one header, which the server doesn't accept.

```
print(flow.request.headers)

Headers[(b'cookie', b's=3AF89B5E-1162-4236-B60D-6E4B05177A14'), (b'cookie', b'fp_token_7c6a6574-d-9894a102cOA5l05EcWM3T5o/whEw='), (b'cookie', b'_gsid=84c83268866a81bad5')]
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Headers.set_all`](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/dev/api/mitmproxy/http.html#Headers.set_all):

```py
flow.request.headers.set_all(
    "cookie", 
    ["first cookie", "second cookie", "third cookie"]
)
```